# How to Connect Skaffold Project to Cluster on Local Network but Different Computer

Tags: web, kubernetes, yaml, skaffold

I've set up a skaffold project with a computer and 3 raspberry Pi's. 2 raspberry pi's form the kubernetes cluster and the third is running as an unsecured docker repository. The 4th computer is a PC I'm using to code on using skaffold to push to the repo and cluster. As I'm new to kubernetes and Skaffold I'm not sure how to configure my skaffold.yaml file to connect to the cluster since it's not on my local host.

I believe that i'm meant to do something about the kubecontext but I'm not sure how I do this when the cluster is not running on the same system as skaffold. Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of some resources or explain to me how to set this up. I can currently push the images successfully to the repo but I just don't know where and what to put in the skaffold.yaml file to get it to do the final stage of creating the pods on the cluster from the images i've made.

Thanks in advance and any questions please let me know. I'll leave the skaffold yaml file below in case that is needed.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: webservice
build:
  insecureRegistries:
  - 192.168.0.10:5000
  artifacts:
  - image: node-webservice-app
    context: src/client
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  - image: node-webservice-server
    context: src/server
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s/webservice.deployment.yaml
    - k8s/webservice.service.yaml
```

Comment: Do you have a kubeconfig on your pc (4th computer)?  If not, go to the master node and run `kubectl config view --flatten` and paste the output to the `~/.kube/config` on your PC and then try running kubectl from the PC. Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skaffold uses "kubectl" binary to deploy to cluster. Your skaffold yaml seems to be correct.

In order to access your Kubernetes cluster, kubectl uses a configuration file. The default configuration file is located at ~/.kube/config and is referred to as the kubeconfig file.

You will need correct `kubeconfig` file in your system with correct context set.
To check current context use this
`kubectl config current-context`